# How to define a range of values for the eps parameter of sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN?

Tags: python, parameters, scikit-learn, range, dbscan

I want to use DBSCAN with the metric [sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) to cluster points that have cosine similarity close to 1 (i.e. whose vectors (from "the" origin) are parallel or almost parallel).

The issue:

eps is the maximum distance between two samples for them to be considered as in the same neighbourhood by DBSCAN - meaning that if the distance between two points is **lower than or equal to** eps, these points are considered neighbours;

but

sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity spits out values between -1 and 1 and I want DBSCAN to consider two points to be neighbours if the distance between them is, say, between 0.75 and 1 - i.e. **greater than or equal to** 0.75.

I see two possible solutions:

1. pass a range of values to the eps parameter of DBSCAN e.g. eps=[0.75,1]
2. Pass the value eps=-0.75 to DBSCAN but (somehow) force it to use the negative of the cosine similarities matrix that is spit out by sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity

I do not know how to implement either of these.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DBSCAN` has a `metric` keyword argument. Docstring:

> metric : string, or callable
>       The metric to use when calculating distance between instances in a
>       feature array. If metric is a string or callable, it must be one of
>       the options allowed by metrics.pairwise.calculate_distance for its
>       metric parameter.
>       If metric is "precomputed", X is assumed to be a distance matrix and
>       must be square. X may be a sparse matrix, in which case only "nonzero"
>       elements may be considered neighbors for DBSCAN.

So probably the easiest thing to do is to precompute a distance matrix using cosine similarity as your distance metric, preprocess the distance matrix such that it fits your bespoke distance criterion (probably something like `D = np.abs(np.abs(CD) -1)`, where CD is your cosine distance matrix), and then set `metric` to `precomputed`, and pass the precomputed distance matrix `D` in for `X`, i.e. the data.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

total_samples = 1000
dimensionality = 3
points = np.random.rand(total_samples, dimensionality)

cosine_distance = cosine_similarity(points)

# option 1) vectors are close to each other if they are parallel
bespoke_distance = np.abs(np.abs(cosine_distance) -1)

# option 2) vectors are close to each other if they point in the same direction
bespoke_distance = np.abs(cosine_distance - 1)

results = DBSCAN(metric='precomputed', eps=0.25).fit(bespoke_distance)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution is working for what I am attempting to do!

Comment: Glad to help. If it solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer. All the best

Comment: Point that snagged me, you have the vars labeled cosine_distance which are actually cosine_similarity

Answer (score 0):

A) check out Generalized DBSCAN which works fine with similarities too.  With cosine, sklearn will supposedly be slow anyway.

B) you can trivially use: cosine distance = 1 - cosine similarity. But that may well cause the sklearn implementation to run in O(n²).

C) you supposedly can even pass `-cosinesimilarity` as precomputed distance matrix and use -0.75 as eps.

d) just make a binary distance matrix (in O(n²) memory, though, so slow), where distance = 0 of the cosine similarity is larger than your threshold, and 0 otherwise. Then use DBSCAN with eps=0.5. it is trivial to show that distance < eps if and only if similarity > threshold.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

1. `dist = np.abs(cos_sim - 1)` accepted answer here
2. `dist = np.arccos(cos_sim) / np.pi` https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3385463/816178
3. `dist = 1 - (sim + 1) / 2` https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3241174/816178

I've found they all work the same in practice for this application (precomputed distances in hierarchical clustering; I've hit the snag too). As I understand #2 is the more mathematically-correct approach; preserving angular distance.